# Set border-bottom to another color if the next item is of a specific class

Tags: html, css, colors, border

### What is happening

I am running into a problem. I have a menu like this:

```
<div id='feeds'>
  <div class='feed'>Super Dense</div>
  <div class='feed'>Everything</div>
  <div class='feed current-feed'>Smashing Magazine Feed</div>
  <div class='feed'>Hot Questions - Stack Exchange</div>
</div>
```

I style this with CSS (I only show the border and background properties here):

```
.feed {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#DDD), to(#CCC));
  border-bottom: solid 1px #AAA;
  border-left: solid 1px #AAA;
  border-right: solid 1px #AAA;
}

.feed:first-child {
  border-top: solid 1px #AAA;
}

.feed.current-feed, .feed:active {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#333), to(#444));
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  border-left: solid 1px #000;
  border-right: solid 1px #000;
}

.feed.current-feed:first-child, .feed:active:first-child {
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
}
```

This is the result ([view on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TmXxv/) WebKit only):
[image: screenshot 1]

<sub>Yes, Jeff, all the extra Stack Exchange feed traffic comes from me constantly reloading my feed reader. Sorry :)</sub>

### The Problem

This might look nice, but there is a little problem. There is a #AAA line above a black box, and this does not look nice (pixel perfection):
[image: screenshot 2]

### My Question

Is there a way in CSS to check if the next element is of a certain class, so I can set `border-bottom` to `solid 1px #000`, or is there another way to solve my problem?

My web app heavily uses JavaScript, so if this is required, it's not a problem, but CSS is cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: You can't check for class names or id's with CSS, but this is easily achievable with JS, are you using a library or vanilla JS?

Comment: @Myles Gray I am using jQuery, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I can think of:

Position every `.feed` relatively:

```
.feed {
    position: relative;
    /* ... */
}
```

Then find the next immediate sibling using the `+` combinator, make it sit above its previous sibling using a greater `z-index` and a negative margin, and give it the desired border (notice that this is a *top* border):

```
.feed + .feed.current-feed, .feed + .feed:active {
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The top black border will sit above the previous sibling's bottom border and thus be visible over it. The W3C box model means that the content height of each `.feed` isn't affected, so an equally thick negative margin is all you need to counter the thickness of the added top border.

Take a look at the [preview](http://jsfiddle.net/TmXxv/1) and see if that's what you're looking for. Also, a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @BoltClock: +1, looks good. @Radek S: You might consider using `ul` and `li` instead of `div`s here. Not that it *really* matters.

Comment: @thirtydot I could, but I like `div`s because they are not pre-styled by the browser except for `display: block;`. :)

Comment: @Radek S: True, but `ul` is the more semantic choice here. All you should need for `ul`/`li` here is this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/TmXxv/4/ (about 3 extra rules)

Comment: Also, CSS resets. (*somebody had to say it...*)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `.parent()` function to do this:

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/TmXxv/3/)